# Autenticação básica Webapi .net40

Tags: asp.net, autenticação

Eu preciso criar uma autenticação básica num projeto Asp.net webapi, mas tem que ser no .Net Framework 4.0, mas todo o conteúdo que encontro na internet é para o 4.5

Algum norte?

Comment: Você deseja autenticação de formulários? Olhe se isto pode te ajudar. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: O Link abaixo explica a solução. Os recursos utilizados poderão ser aplicados no .net 4 também: [Autenticação básica](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/restful-day-sharp5-security-in-web-apis-basic-authentication-a/)